# How do I publish the Azure API Management developer portal changes from one instance to another instance?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How do I publish the Azure API Management developer portal changes from one instance to another instance?

I have 2 instances of Azure API management, dev-01-apim and tst-01-apim

I am making changes to the developer portal instance of dev-01-apim and now that developer portal changes I want to deploy to tst-01-apim instance.

how do I publish these changes using the automation or DevOps process?.

Answer (score 2):

You can check wiki page on GitHub project repo.
Please follow these docs
https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/wiki/Migrate-portal-between-services